# Show that $u$ is increasing if $u''=a(t)u+b(t)u'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

All functions are defined in an open interval $I$, and $a,b$ are continuous. The problem asked me to show that $u$ is monotonically increasing in $\{t\geq t_0:t\in I\}$, provided that $u''=a(t)u+b(t)u'$, and $u(t_0)=0$, $u'(t_0)=1$, $a(t)>0$ for all $t$.

I have so far found that:
$$u''(t_0)= a(t_0)u(t_0)+b(t_0)u'(t_0)=b(t_0) $$ Also I wrote the problem as $$u'(t)=1+\int_{t_0}^t a(s)u(s)+b(s)u'(s)ds $$ I tried exploring the methods $u(t)>u(s)$ if $t>s$, and even $u'(t)>0$ for $t\geq t_0$, but goes nowhere. I'm don't see more directions to take not sure how to go from here, any idea is appreciated
**I have added the original problem** came from some chapters I found out somewhere, but without author, problem and chapter are added.
[image: Original Problem]

[image]

Comment: Given the generality of the statement one could make a as small as possible (keeping it positive) and making the first addend negligible. In the meanwhile b can be made arbitrarily large and negative... I find it difficult now to imagine that u' can remain positive in such circumstances... Where does the statement come from?

Comment: @Thomas I have added an update, but It doesn't has author

Comment: Thanks for the update :)

Comment: I described a visual description of the argument of Hagen von Eitzen, I hope it is correct ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U$ be the open interior of $\{\,t>t_0\mid u'(t)\le 0\,\}$. Assume $U\ne\emptyset$  and let $\tau=\inf U$. As $u'(t_0)>0$ and $u'$ is continuous, we have $\tau>t_0$ and clearly $u'(\tau)=0$. As $u'$ is non-negative on $[t_0,\tau)$ and positive near $t_0$, we conclude that $u$ is positive on $(t_0,\tau]$. Therefore $u''(\tau)=a(\tau)u(\tau)>0$. That means that $u'$ changes sign from negative to positive at $\tau$, contradiction the definition of $\tau$. Hence $U$ is empty and so $u$ is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is a visual argument, that I think leads to a visual intepretation of the argument already given by Hagen Von Eitzen .

If we convert the differential equation to a system of first order equations we can visualize the associated vector field.

The system is not autonomous and therefore the vector field depends on time but:

- when $v=0$, it equals to $a(t)u \hat{v}$ and it points in the first quadrant, because $a>0$;
- when $u=0$, the $u$ component is time independent and positive (equal to zero only in the origin). The $v$ component changes with time ;

In the figure I plotted a visualization of the vector field at an arbitrary time t.

It visually follows (and I think the argument can be made rigorous following arguments similar to the ones given by Hagen von Eitzen) that if we start in the first quadrant, we cannot escape it. Therefore $v=u'$ will remain always positive, i.e. the function is monotonous.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas I think it helps clarifying things.